# How do I add new children to collections in Mongodb with java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

I want to create a tree data model in `MongoDb`. how do I add a new child to a previously made record. then I will add new kids to that boy. This way the data will be branched continuously.

For example, there is such a data.

```
  {
"_id": ObjectId("5c540f65da774b2fa469883f"),
"id": "aba30930-3e72-44d0-99bb-f49213f86d76",
"type": "low",
"value": "5.23",
"low": {
    "value": "5.25",
    "id": "0a13f955-8373-45fd-96c4-3637e5da0d24",
    "type": "low"

    }
}
```

I want to add a new child into `low` later.

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5c540f65da774b2fa469883f"),
"id": "aba30930-3e72-44d0-99bb-f49213f86d76",
"type": "low",
"value": "5.23",
"low": {
    "value": "5.25",
    "id": "0a13f955-8373-45fd-96c4-3637e5da0d24",
    "type": "low",
    "low": {
        "value": "5.24",
        "id": "0a13f955-8373-45fd-96c4-3637e5da0d24",
        "type": "low"
    },
   "high": {
        "value": "5.26",
        "id": "0a13f955-8373-45fd-96c4-3637e5da0d24",
        "type": "high"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to do that

```
newDocument.append("low",new BasicDBObject().append("value", 
    "5.25").append("id", id).append("type", "low").append("low",
    new BasicDBObject().append("value", "5.24").append("id", 
    id).append("type","low")));
```

Comment: you can use  mongo db update query it will autmoatically create new child.plese provide more details to question

Comment: How can I reference children? if I want to add to the child of the child of the child. @Tejal